# Date fetched from Firebase not being displayed in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

- I have fetched `dateOfEvent` value from `FirebaseFirestore` but while displaying the `date` fetched from the db it is not being displayed.
- Rather when I click on it to select the date, the date which is fetched is selected by default.
  Below is the gif that will make you understand easily.

[image]

- So for the above gif the `Date of Event` fetched is `30-06-2009` and `Deadline of Event` is `29-06-2009` (just the dummy value so ignore the dates)
- I want to display the `date` fetched from the `firebase` but for some reason it is not being displayed.
- Code

```
    // date of event
    DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
    TextEditingController dateController = TextEditingController();
    DateTime dateOfEvent = eventDate;
    Future _selectDate(context) async {
      final DateTime pickedEvent = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: eventDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(1940),
        lastDate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 4380)),
        helpText: 'Select Date of Event',
        fieldLabelText: 'Enter date of Event',
        builder: (context, child) {
          return Theme(
            data: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
              colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
                primary: primaryColor, // highlighed date color
                onPrimary: Colors.black, // highlighted date text color
                surface: primaryColor, // header color
                onSurface:
                    Colors.grey[800], // header text & calendar text color
              ),
              dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white, // calendar bg color
              textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: secondaryColor, // button text color
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: child,
          );
        },
      );
      if (pickedEvent != null && pickedEvent != dateOfEvent) {
        setState(() {
          dateOfEvent = pickedEvent;
          print(dateOfEvent);
        });
      }
    }
..
..
// Date of event
                        TextFormField(
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          controller: dateController,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: Icon(
                              Icons.date_range,
                              color: secondaryColor,
                            ),
                            labelText: 'Date of Event',
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: formFieldFillColor,
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondaryColor),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            ),
                            focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondaryColor),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onTap: () async {
                            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                            await _selectDate(context);
                            dateController.text =
                                "${DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(dateOfEvent.toLocal())}"
                                    .split(' ')[0];
                          },
                        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably the date is not being display because the way is being fetch from the data base, the timestamp in firebase has a range value of:

```
Range is from 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z to 9999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z
```

you can find more information [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp)

I think that if you transform that timestamp to a string for example using the function `toString()` you will be able to display it in the application.